# Liferay Application Display Template - Get Velocity variables

Tags: liferay, freemarker

I am writing an Application Display Template for an Asset Publisher in Liferay (6.2 GA5) in Freemarker and I want to display the author and the creation date. A while ago I needed the same variables for a template and I found matching Velocity variables: 
`$reserved-article-author-name` & `$reserved-article-create-date.data`

To use Velocity variables in FreeMarker, I called them like this: `${.vars['reserved-article-author-name'].data}`

In my Template, it works fine, in my ADT, it throws an error:

> Expression .vars['reserved-article-author-name'] is undefined

How do you manage to get these variables to work in my ADT or is there an alternative way to get this information?

Comment: Note that since FreeMarker 2.3.22 you can write `reserved\-article\-author\-name` instead of `.vars['reserved-article-author-name']`. I'm not sure which Liferay version comes with 2.3.22+ though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those "reserved article" variables are only set when processing Web Content Templates.

With ADTs you have much more fine-grained access to the displayed assets but have to use a different way of accessing, since those reserved variables aren't available. Assets have a generic set of metadata (name, date, title, etc) that you can access. For your example, the code would be:

```
<#if entries?has_content>
    <#list entries as curEntry>
        Title: ${curEntry.getTitle(locale)}
        Create Date: ${curEntry.createDate?date}
        Author: ${curEntry.userName}
    </#list>
</#if>
```

Check out this [Rich Summary for Asset Publisher](https://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Rich+Summary+for+Asset+Publisher) to see how to access metadata for specific asset types (blogs, wikis, etc).